# Terraform remote state azure

Tags: azure, terraform

I have worked with terraform before, where terraform can place the tfstate files in S3. Does terraform also support azure blob storage as a backend? What would be the commands to set the backend to be azure blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Terraform 0.7](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (not currently released but you can compile from source) support for Azure blob storage has been [added](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/7064).

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for some commands, so I'm adding a little more detail in case anyone needs it. I'm using Terraform v0.12.24 and azurerm provider v2.6.0. You need two things:

1. Create a storage account (general purpose v2) and a container for storing your states.
2. Configure your environment and your main.tf

As for the second point, your terraform block in main.tf should contain a "azurerm" backend:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "=0.12.24"
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "abcd1234"
    container_name       = "tfstatecontainer"
    key                  = "example.prod.terraform.tfstate"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.6.0"
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
}
```

Before calling to plan or apply, init the ARM_ACCESS_KEY variable with a bash export:

```
export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=<storage access key>
```

Finally, run the init command:

```
terraform init
```

Now, if you run terraform plan you will see the tfstate created in the container. Azure has a file locking feature built in, in case anyone tries to update the state file at the same time.